# Distribution of an unordered set of random variables

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

Suppose we have a set of deterministic points $y_{1}, \dots, y_{m} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let
$T : \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{n'}$ be a random function.

Suppose that for $i=1,\dots,n$ we have well-defined random variables:
$$
  X_{i}(\omega) = T(y_{i}, \omega).
$$

We can then study the joint distribution of the $n$-tuple $X = (X_{1},X_{2},\dots,X_{n})$ via its characteristic function
$$
  \phi(t_{1},\dots,t_{n}) = \mathbf{E}_{X}\left[\exp\left(i\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle X_{i}, t_{i} \rangle\right)\right].
$$

However, I am interested in understanding the random variables $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}$ as an unordered set $\{X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}\}$. For example, upon suitable conditions on the points $y_{1},\dots,y_{n}$ and the random map $T$, I am interested in situations where I could show that the set $\{X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\}$ is distributed as $n$ random draws from some common distribution $\mu$. In other words, I would like to "forget" the indices of $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}$.

For this problem, the best I could come up with is to study the distribution of the $n$-tuple $(X_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, X_{\sigma(n)})$, where $\sigma : \{1,\dots, n\} \to \{1,\dots,n\}$ is a bijection chosen uniformly at random among all possible bijections (i.e., a random permutation). However, I am wondering if there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\si{\sigma}\newcommand\B{\mathcal B}\newcommand\G{\mathcal G}$This can be done in a straightforward manner, as follows.

For each $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in(\R^{n'})^n$, let
$$f_{n,n'}((x_1,\dots,x_n)):=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}.$$
Let
$$R_{n,n'}:=\{\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\colon(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in(\R^{n'})^n\}.$$
Let $\B((\R^{n'})^n)$ denote the Borel $\si$-algebra over $(\R^{n'})^n$. Let
$$\G_{n,n'}:=\{C\subseteq R_{n,n'}\colon f_{n,n'}^{-1}(C)\in\B((\R^{n'})^n)\}.$$
Then $\G_{n,n'}$ is a $\si$-algebra over $R_{n,n'}$, and the map $f_{n,n'}\colon(\R^{n'})^n\to R_{n,n'}$ is $(\B((\R^{n'})^n),\G_{n,n'})$-measurable.

For the random $n$-tuple $X$ as in your post, let $Y:=f_{n,n'}(X)$. Then $Y$ is a random set with values in $R_{n,n'}$; more precisely, $Y$ is a measurable map from $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ to $(R_{n,n'},\G_{n,n'})$. If $P_X$ is the distribution of $X$, then the distribution of $Y$ is the pushforward of $P_X$ under the map $f_{n,n'}$.

---

However, the very idea of a random set (instead of a random tuple) does not seem useful to me, because the structure of the set $R_{n,n'}$ of sets is significantly more complicated then the product set $(\R^{n'})^n$ of $n$-tuples of vectors in $\R^{n'}$. In particular, as in the OP, one may want to try to identify a set $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ with the set $\Pi_{(x_1,\dots,x_n)}:=
\{(x_{\pi(1)},\dots,x_{\pi(n)})\colon\pi\in S_n\}$, where $S_n$ is the $n$th symmetric group. Yet, this idea will not work, because (say) $\{1,1,2\}=\{1,2\}$ but $\Pi_{(1,1,2)} \ne\Pi_{(1,2)}$. However, if, despite my impression, this idea of a random set is useful somewhere, then hopefully the OP will tell us about such a use.